# How to iterate collection pairs

Tags: groovy

Here is a collection in Groovy:

```
def z = [name: ['Bob', 'Alex'], surname: ['Smith', 'Brown']]
```

How can I iterate this to get name,surname pair for each person?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easiest is likely `transpose()`:

```
[z.name, z.surname].transpose()
```