# Error iterating pairs in sequences

Tags: scala, transpose

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320840/how-to-iterate-collection-pairs), I would expect the following to work:

```
Seq( Seq(1,2,3) , Seq(4,5,6) ).transpose()
```

but alas:

```
error: not enough arguments for method transpose: (implicit asTraversable: 
Seq[Int] => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[B])Seq[Seq[B]].
Unspecified value parameter asTraversable.
          Seq( Seq(1,2,3) , Seq(4,5,6) ).transpose()
```

Also, I can't seem to find [any reference to transpose on the scala docs](http://docs.scala-lang.org/search.html?q=transpose), although [Seq refers it](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Seq.html)

Providing the identity, it seems to work somehow:

```
scala> Seq( Seq(1,2,3) , Seq(4,5,6) ).transpose( a => a)
res10: Seq[Seq[Int]] = List(List(1, 4), List(2, 5), List(3, 6))
```

But still returns List instead of Seq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use it without parentheses:

```
Seq( Seq(1,2,3) , Seq(4,5,6) ).transpose
//res0: Seq[Seq[Int]] = List(List(1, 4), List(2, 5), List(3, 6))
```

*But still returns List instead of Seq*

Well, actually [List is inheritor of Seq](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections.immutable.png), so after all you got a Seq (look at the left part of result).

The reason of such behaviour is that transpose actually defined as a function **with** argument, but since it's argument defined as [implicit](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/114) you have an option to delegate work of substituting argument to scala compiler (it will perform compile-time lookup for you).

If you writing parentheses, either function has to have overloaded form with no arguments, e.g.

```
def transpose() = ...
```

or you have to write something inside them (it's actually matter of syntax).

Comment: Oh, I see! I still don't understand exactly how calling without braces works. Is scala providing the default argument in this case? Why doesn't it do so when using braces?